# Securing application on windows 10

Tags: windows, appsec

I need to figure out how to run my application on Windows 10.

1. My application would run on an app-specific account (let's called it "App").
2. My application saves/reads PDFs from the folder "PDF". I need to make sure that ONLY the application and admin users may enter this folder. So I would add rights - so only admins and App can work with this folder.
3. Public key for encrypting these PDF is in the applications folder called "resources". I would add the same rights as I wrote in point 2. I need to make sure that no one else can copy that public key (only app and admin).

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Why do you want to protect the public key? Shouldn't you protect the private key? What do you want to prevent? These are fine measures, but what do you not want to happen? What do you want to protect against? This is a little like asking "is a moat a good way to secure my home?" Well, yes, against some things but not others, and moats are very inefficient.

Comment: ...note that if you encrypt with a public key, you would also require a _private_ key to be able to read those PDFs - at which point you could just use a symmetric key.  As far as I know, the "traditional" way to do this on Windows would be to create a service that acts as an API for a client application, almost as if this is was a web app, but this is only useful if the user does not have admin credentials (ie, in a corporate scenario).